# install "atom-beautify@0.33.0" failed

Tags: package, installation, atom-beautify

I have installed the atom-beautify packages and I received this notify:

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.4.0
gyp info using node@6.9.5 | win32 | x64
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/iojs-v2.0.5.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/iojs-v2.0.5.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! install error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: read ECONNRESET
gyp ERR! stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:569:26)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\Quy Nguyen\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.30.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Quy Nguyen\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.30.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "install" "--runtime=electron" "--target=2.0.5" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--arch=x64" "--ensure"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Quy Nguyen\.atom
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

But sometimes I have different output like that:

```
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated @types/commander@2.12.2: This is a stub types definition for commander (https://github.com/tj/commander.js). commander provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/commander installed!
npm WARN deprecated jscs-preset-wikimedia@1.0.1: Deprecated in favour of eslint-config-wikimedia. -- https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T118941
npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.17134
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\Quy Nguyen\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.30.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Quy Nguyen\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.30.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "C:\\Users\\Quy Nguyen\\.atom\\.apm\\.apmrc" "--userconfig" "C:\\Users\\Quy Nguyen\\.atom\\.apmrc" "install" "C:\\Users\\QUYNGU~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\d-11882-10676-1pd8cj3.buptceg66r\\package.tgz" "--runtime=electron" "--target=2.0.5" "--arch=x64" "--global-style" "--msvs_version=2015"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code EREADFILE

npm ERR! Error extracting C:\Users\Quy Nguyen\.atom\.apm\marko\4.13.3\package.tgz archive: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Quy Nguyen\.atom\.apm\marko\4.13.3\package.tgz'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\QUYNGU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11882-10676-1ak13y1.o2hmklz0k9\npm-debug.log
```

I cannot understand how it works.

Thanks for your helps!

Comment: To install node-gyp on windows you may need build tools. node-gyp is required for this package

Comment: I tried many solution that were available online and none of them worked. Could you please point me how to use build tools? Is it must used “Bash On Ubuntu On Windows 10”? Because i'm working on windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On Linux/Mac, the issue is solved by taking the following steps:**

Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)

```
cd /home/your_username/.atom/.apm/marko

ln -s 4.13.4 4.13.3

apm install atom-beautify
```

On Windows, you can use Git Bash and taking the above steps.

**Or, on Windows taking the following steps:**

Open cmd/powershell

```
cd C:\Users\your_username\.atom\.apm\marko

mklink /J 4.13.3 4.13.4

apm install atom-beautify
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't fix the problem for me.

Comment: @Garret Wilson, I used apm install atom-beautify and it worked although installation didn't work in the past. And I found out your issue on git and it was explained clearly. You can refer it on [link](https://github.com/atom/apm/issues/666)

Comment: I think I may have missed the part about changing the directory. (I was trying to get around several levels of problems.) I eventually fixed it by using a similar command, so I probably missed the `cd`. Anyway, for future posts, I recommend your putting commands as code or a code block, so that they stand out. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I am using windows 10 64 bit. I almost ripped my head of falling install atom-beautify. I was receiving "npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file". I tried everything. At last I reinstalled atom then deleted the .apm file and finally was able to install atom-beautify package. Hope this information help someone.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the .apm folder I was able to install the atom-beautify package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this Works!

**For MAC/LINUX**:

Open terminal

```
cd /home/your_username/.atom/.apm/marko

ln -s 4.13.4 4.13.3

apm install atom-beautify
```

**For WINDOWS** :

Open cmd/powershell

```
cd C:\Users\your_username\.atom\.apm\marko

mklink /J 4.13.3 4.13.4

apm install atom-beautify
```

Answer (score -1):

Turning off the Windows firewall and antivirus worked for me.

Comment: Would you like to elaborate why you feel that the needed purposes of firewall and antimalware are not needed with your solution? This information seems to be missing from your post, because obviously you are not knowingly making yourself vulnerable to this extreme level....